# Customize Stackblitz Angular project template

Tags: angular, typescript, stackblitz

I'm about to fork and customize Stackblitz Angular CLI project template which is likely stored at [github.com/stackblitz/angular-cli-template](https://github.com/stackblitz/angular-cli-template).

*The primary objective here is to modify TypeScript configuration and change `target` from `es5` to `es6`.*

According to [the documentation](https://stackblitz.com/docs#import-from-github), it should be available for import as [stackblitz.com/github/stackblitz/angular-cli-template](https://stackblitz.com/github/stackblitz/angular-cli-template), but this results in an error:

> Import error, can't find file:
>
> src/main.ts

Indeed, there is no src/main.ts in the repository, and it looks very different from [regular Stackblitz Angular CLI project](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular):

[image: stackblitz]

Notice that there's a bunch of files that don't exist in regular project (or more specifically, they are hidden, because they appear when the project is exported from Stackblitz).

I've tried to change TS configuration in regular project, it seems that it is expected to be located at `/tsconfig.app.json`, relatively to visible project root ([a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njp9za?file=tsconfig.app.json)). I've also tried to make it fail by setting `module` to `amd`, but this didn't work. It seems like `tsconfig.app.json` affects nothing, but when *Export* is clicked, `tsconfig.app.json` is actually changed.

Is [github.com/stackblitz/angular-cli-template](https://github.com/stackblitz/angular-cli-template) actual project template that is used by Stackblitz?

If it's not actual template, where can actual Angular project template be forked, and what should Stackblitz workable forked template look like to be imported as `stackblitz.com/github/{GH_USERNAME}/{REPO_NAME}` as described in the documentation?

How can TypeScript configuration be modified for Stackblitz Angular project?

Comment: Regarding to your question, I faced alot of problems using stackblitz and I manage to have more success over codesandbox.io , so you can check it out too before trying too hard with stackblitz. goodluck

Comment: @dAxx_ I probably will. It has same problem as Stackblitz with inability to recover unsaved code if a tab was closed or stopped responding, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

For others looking for answer:

As of April 2020, when you mouse over the stackblitz lightning logo in the top left, it expands to 'New Project' where you can choose 1 of 11 templates.

The resulting url does not appear to be guessable.